# Enter a value into a textbox using python and selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I am having some issues inputting a value into a textbox using selenium and python. I have tried out quite a few methods but haven't been able to make much progress.

This is what the websites HTML looks like (specifically the textbox I am looking to input a value into)

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="location" id="location"  placeholder="Zip Code or City, State (e.g, 12345 or New York, NY)">&nbsp;&nbsp;<i class="active fa fa-check-circle"></i>
```

I am trying to enter the value 11415 for now, and have done this

```
 WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(By.XPATH, "//input[@class='form-control' and @id='location']")).send_keys("11415")
```

Here is the website if you'd like to check it out:
https://www.fairhealthconsumer.org/medical/zip

And here is my full code for reference (the commented out code is other attempts I've made to solve this!)

```
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
import time
import os
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

from selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement import WebElement
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys



s=Service('/Users/[name]/Desktop/chromedriver')

chromeOptions = Options()
chromeOptions.headless = False
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s, options=chromeOptions)

list_data = []
    
def initalize_browser():
    # load website
    driver.get("https://www.fairhealthconsumer.org/")
    driver.maximize_window()

    driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//button[@class="mx-auto green-btn btnHref"]').click()

    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, ".//*[@for='radio3']/span"))).click()
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH, ".//*[@for='radio3']//span[@class='pt-2 border-top border-white']").click()
    
    # inputElement = driver.find_element_by_id("location")
    # inputElement.send_keys('11415')
    
    # inputElement.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)

    driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//button[@class="button custom-bgcolor-secondary next selected"]').click()

    # driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="location"]').click()
    # driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//text[@id="location"]').send_keys("11415")

    # WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'location'))).send_keys('11415')
    # button_to_be_clicked = browser.find_element(By.ID, 'button-submit')
    # button_to_be_clicked.click()

    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(By.XPATH, "//input[@class='form-control' and @id='location']")).send_keys("11415")

    print(driver.page_source)

initalize_browser()


driver.quit
```

I have watched a ton of videos and read some answers on stack overflow, but I believe the syntax has changed and I haven't found too much info. I would really appreciate any help, thank you so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the https://github.com/seleniumbase/SeleniumBase Recorder & Export tool to generate a working script.

First `pip install seleniumbase`, then run with `pytest` or `python`:

```py
from seleniumbase import BaseCase

class HealthSiteTest(BaseCase):
    def test_health_site(self):
        self.open("https://www.fairhealthconsumer.org/")
        self.click('button:contains("Medical and Hospital Costs")')
        self.click('label[for="radio3"] span i:nth-of-type(2)')
        self.click('label[for="radio3"] mark span')
        self.type("input#location", "11415")
        self.click('a[href="/medical/select-medical-totalcost"]')
        self.assert_text("Select the type of care", "h1")

# When run with "python" instead of "pytest"
if __name__ == "__main__":
    from pytest import main
    main([__file__])
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Works perfectly. I'll be playing around with this tool. Thanks again!